# Build multiple pages using quasar

Tags: node.js, npm, quasar-framework, quasar

I need to build a multi-page website using Quasar to host on Netlify but Quasar is only building the `index.html`.

I have tried to use `Quasar build` and `Quasar build --mode ssr`. Both have failed in building more than the `index.html`.

Is there a way to accomplish multiple pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of SPA is excellent, however it still does not suite everybody's needs, an example is having a backend app (for example django) and not willing to spend a lot of time to develop a rest api or graphql for it to serve the SPA contents.

Quasar cli at the end of the day in its core is just a webpack config that you can customize to achieve whatever you want that webpack can do, including multi page apps, here is a quick way to achieve this:

`apps/myapp/pages.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  main_page: {
    entry: `${__dirname}/pages/main/main_page.js`
  }
  blog_entry_page: {
    entry: `${__dirname}/pages/blog/blog_entry_page.js`
  }
  ...
}
```

`quasar.conf.js`:

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('@quasar/app/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin')
const pages = require('./apps/myapp/pages')

module.exports = function (ctx) {
  return {
    ...
    build: {
      ...
      extendWebpack (cfg) {
        ...
        Object.keys(pages).forEach(function (page) {
          // Add page webpack entry
          cfg.entry[page] = pages[page].entry

          // Output an html file for the page
          cfg.plugins.push(
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
              template: 'mytemplate.html',
              filename: `html/${page}.html`,
              chunks: [page]
            })
          )
        })
        ...
      }
    }
  }
```

The above is a simplified example just to demonstrate the concept, for a complete and functional example see: https://gitlab.com/noor-projects/noor/tree/master/quasar-cli
(check this [commit](https://gitlab.com/noor-projects/noor/commit/a0769a68e3ab053fe6d9aa27fedb12c5c9d4286b#d0b72a03e8c15fdb117c8a846ebe420161a9e8a4) to know about what was added to enable MPA support)

Answer (score 2):

Quasar framework builds single page apps by default, that is, your index.html page is the only page, and instead of going to different static pages, it uses the Vue router to load dynamic pages and components to your hearts content :)

Check out this Quasar document that explains with SPA (Single Page Apps) are and how they work (and why it's the best thing to do):
https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-spa/introduction#Introduction

Check out this Quasar document to learn how to add more routes (pages) to your app:
https://quasar.dev/layout/routing-with-layouts-and-pages#Defining-Routes

Quasar Framework is definitely the way to go, so keep at it. I'd be happy to walk you through anything.  I've used the framework for nearly a dozen clients and many have gone off to recently be valued in the millions by investors. Quasar is the best mix for any platform you can think of, from a simple site to a complex web and mobile app that will be used by millions of people; it gets the job done with flying colors.

I've been writing apps and web sites for 20 years, nothing as easy to work with as Quasar has ever come along before it. You will love it!

Comment: Nick Steele I appreciate your answer! you are the one teaching us through transactive.io right?

Comment: :O Yes that's me. Although Angelica has taken it over and is moving to more planned sessions.  Small world! :)

Comment: I thought I recognized that name I do contract work for CentralApp and that how I heard about that training you was offering lol.

Comment: Awesome! I remember your name now that you mentioned it. Well if you would like a walk through or anything, email me at nick@transactive.io and I'd be glad to help.

Comment: Alright I’ll do some research into it first. I might end up asking you how to integrate a Rails backend if you me familiar with that.